# How to pass database name dynamically to RoundHousE

Tags: sql-server, database, roundhouse

I am trying to setup the RoundHousE project in my application to handle the database migration and version handling. I am following [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/712835/How-to-setup-database-versioning-tool-RoundhousE) article. It is fine as far as I know the database name exactly.

But I am not able to find, how should I handle the dynamic name of databases, because in my application I have separate database for each client, and list of these databases in a table in my main database. So name goes like: client1_db, client2_db etc.

Any solution or pointer towards the solution will be a great help.

Answer (score 1):

A pointer towards the solution - The wiki https://github.com/chucknorris/roundhouse/wiki

Asking about passing the database name dynamically is a bit weird to me as when you run `rh.exe` or use the embedded DLL, database name is one of the required arguments. So you *always* have to pass the name dynamically. See https://github.com/chucknorris/roundhouse/wiki/ConfigurationOptions#main-stuff

Reading and trying to understand what you are asking, it seems you have a list of database names in a main database somewhere that you want to give to RoundhousE? To do that you would need to create something custom that can gather the name of the database(s) you are looking for and provide the result to RoundhousE.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Will try to follow it and get it working for me.